# Reading the file from a location extracted from getProperty

Tags: java

I am not very good with Java and am having a problem in understanding how to read the file efficiently so it is independent of the enviroment where my application executes.
Below i will try to explain what i am trying to do.
I have a configProperty.java

```
private ConfigProperty() {
prop = new Properties();
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test/util/CSV.properties");
try {
    prop.load(in);
    in.close();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

the CSV.properties looks something like this

```
a=Folder\\1.csv
b=Folder\\2.csv
c=Folder\\3.csv
```

and then in one of the class where i am using these it is something like

```
ConfigProperty.getInstance();
String path = ConfigProperty.getProp().getProperty("a");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
```

By using the string variable path in this way in the BufferedReader(new FileReader) parameter i am limiting my applications to always fetch the path of "Folder/1.csv", "Folder/2.csv" and "Folder/3.csv" from the canonical path and the canonical path seems to be different for different IDE and enviroments.
At the end,i hope i am making sense here and am able to convey my problem. ;). Also, if i may request please explain in detail.

Comment: Nope, you are not explaining your question at all.

Comment: let me re-think and edit then :)

Comment: "my folder containing 1.csv, 2.csv and 3.csv are dependent of the enviroment" How does it depend on the environment?

Comment: you aren't using a canonical path anywhere, only relative paths.  are you referring to the "working directory" of the running java process?

Comment: what i meant to say was that the my Folder should be located in the path printed by ..println(getCanonicalPath). and the getCanonicalPath prints different paths in different IDEs..

Comment: the easiest way in my opinion would be to differ the OS's - so make two (or more) copies of /test/util/CSV.properties and make statement if -> running win/linux/mac etc. load different file with different paths; but it will be 'brute force' method :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want read some files, best way is to put them in your jar, as resource.

If you want read/write files somewhere in the user environment, best way (in my opinion) is to ask where to the user, at any point of installation / application.Save the location with a Preference.